# How can i bind android button to website button

Tags: javascript, java, android

I have a android activity it contains 2 edittext and 1 button this activity bind with web page and my button need to press web page log in button. Web page button has got javascript function like that

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

how can i use that func. in my activity? And  i used AsyncTask class any suggestion or help ? Thanks anyway. Have a nice day.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654386/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-directly-from-an-activity-in-android this one. it might be the one you are looking for.

Comment: I saw this one it is using webview i want to call JS function background not foreground @MayankPandya